# responsive dropdown menu will not close

Tags: javascript, html, css, togglebutton

I made this simple dropdown menu for my site. Using CSS, I made everything as it should be, but there is something wrong with my js file. Can anybody help me with how I can change js file so that dropdown menu collapse (close) when I press the "hamburger" button (toggleMenu) second time. If not, last image tag in a div "dropdown-menu-content" is a close icon, but closeMenu() function is not working. Nothing happens when I click it.

HTML and js files are following. Thank you.

```js
//Menu-toggle button
function toggleMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('menu-display');

  if (menuBox.style.display == "block") {
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function closeMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('menu-display');
  menuBox.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <button id="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <img src="images/menu_icon_blue.png" alt="menu_btn">
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-display">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-content">
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index_eng.html" class="active">HJEM</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="om_eng.html">OM OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="priser_eng.html">PRISER</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="kontakt_eng.php">KONTAKT OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index.html">NORSK</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="#"><img src="images/close_icon_blue.png" alt="close"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end dropdown menu -->
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.getElementById('dropdown-menu-display')` instead of `document.getElementById('menu-display')`? You can confirm this by looking into the JavaScript Web Console to check if theres an JavaScript error.

Comment: Not only that there is no id in that name. create one!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use jQuery

CSS

```
#menu-display{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#dropdown-btn').click(function(
    $('#dropdown-menu-display').toggleClass('menu-display');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Menu-toggle button
function toggleMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu-display');

  if (menuBox.style.display == "block") {
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function closeMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu-display');
  menuBox.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <button id="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <img src="images/menu_icon_blue.png" alt="menu_btn">
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-display" id="dropdown-menu-display">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-content">
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index_eng.html" class="active">HJEM</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="om_eng.html">OM OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="priser_eng.html">PRISER</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="kontakt_eng.php">KONTAKT OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index.html">NORSK</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="#"><img src="images/close_icon_blue.png" alt="close"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end dropdown menu -->
```

Here is the working script! 
Errors: You are getting the element by **ID** but there is no id called **menu-display**. 
Solution: I have added *id="dropdown-menu-display"* along with the class and used this id in the *toggleMenu() and closeMenu()* function!

Comment: thank you so much... Didn't see I put the class in stead of id :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
var menuBox = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

//Menu-toggle button
function toggleMenu() {
  if(menuBox.style.display == "block") {
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function closeMenu(){
  menuBox.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-display {display: none}
.dropdown-menu-display { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 5px; width: 100px}
.dropdown-menu-content a {display:block; outline:0; text-decoration: none}
.dropdown-menu-content a:hover {background-color: #eee}
```

```html
<!-- dropdown menu -->
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <button id="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    Button
  </button>
  <div id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu-display">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-content">
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index_eng.html" class="active">HJEM</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="om_eng.html">OM OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="priser_eng.html">PRISER</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="kontakt_eng.php">KONTAKT OSS</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="index.html">NORSK</a>
      <a onclick="closeMenu()" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end dropdown menu -->
```

You have one omission, you are calling

```
var menuBox = document.getElementById('menu-display');
```

however, you have defined your div as a class;

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-display">
...
</div>
```

So to get it working, you either have to to give your **dropdown-menu-display** an id or you need to get the element with **document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu-display')**

Here is a working config, where I have given your menu div and id and cached its element..